# borderRightWidth and borderBottomWidth to View in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want below image design. I tried `borderRightWidth` and `borderBottomWidth` but it can merge at right bottom corner. I also don't want to put extra `<View>` outside/inside main `<View>`.

What i want:

[image]

What i already achieved:

[image]

My code:

```js
<View style={styles.brand_container}>
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',marginBottom: 10,}}>
     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.brand_img_container}>
         <Image source={Images.brand_logo.brand_1} style={styles.brand_img} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.brand_img_container}>
         <Image source={Images.brand_logo.brand_2} style={styles.brand_img} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.brand_img_container, {borderRightWidth: 0}]}>
        <Image source={Images.brand_logo.brand_3} style={styles.brand_img} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',}}>
     <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.brand_img_container, {borderBottomWidth: 0}]}>
        <Image source={Images.brand_logo.brand_4} style={styles.brand_img} />
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.brand_img_container, {borderBottomWidth: 0}]}>
       <Image source={Images.brand_logo.brand_5} style={styles.brand_img} />
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.brand_img_container, {border: 0}]}>
        <Image source={Images.brand_logo.brand_6} style={styles.brand_img} />
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
</View>
```

Styling:

```css
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  brand_img_container: {
        flex: 1, 
        height: 150, 
        margin: 5, 
        padding: 10, 
        borderRightWidth: 1, 
        borderBottomWidth: 1, 
        alignItems: 'center', 
        justifyContent: 'center'
  }, 
  brand_img: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use blank view to generate the line instead of using right or left border of existing view. It will be tough to make alignment as compare with your VD. Blank view you early push up,down,left or right.

For Example: You can below code to draw vertical and horizontal line respectively. It will comparatively easy to align.

```
<View style={{
        height: 150,
        borderColor: "grey",
        borderWidth: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }} />



      <View style={{
        width: 150,
        height: 1,
        borderColor: "grey",
        borderWidth: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }} />
```

Comment: ya I know this but as I indicate in my question I don't want to give style using blank `<View>`

Comment: Oh! yeah, sorry i overlooked.